# How to say that one is not staying as something

Tags: negation

A recent Slow German Podcast had the following sentence:

> Natürlich blieb Einstein kein Angestellter am Patentamt.

It seems to me that it might be better to say it this way:

> Natürlich blieb Einstein einen Angestellter des Patentamt nicht.

The first sentence says that Einstein was staying as not an employee -- he was not an employee and he was staying that way. The second sentence says that Einstein was not staying as an employee, which is the correct meaning -- he was an employee but he would not stay one. Opinions, please?

Comment: This is not a matter of opinion. Your emendation is simply wrong on several levels.

Comment: Note "bleiben" does not exclusively mean "stay" (especially not here). You might want to look up a few more meanings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Germans negate differently than the English, in case of the indefinite article.

> Hast Du **ein** Auto? *Do you have a car*
> Nein, ich habe **kein** Auto. *No, I do not have a car*. (literally: I have **no** car).
>
> Bist Du (ein) Lehrer?  *Are you a teacher?*
> Nein, ich bin **kein** Lehrer. *No, I'm not a teacher*

Compare this to:

> Bist Du der Lehrer? *Are you the teacher?*
> Nein, ich bin nicht der Lehrer. Tatsächlich bin ich gar kein Lehrer. *No, I'm not the teacher. As a matter of fact I'm not a teacher at all.*

You may have asked for opinions, but objectively, your first sentence is correct and your second example is not.

You can formulate the sentence with *nicht* however, if you want to make clear, that he didn't stay in the Patentamt, but at another place. Please note the position of *nicht*. Also, it takes the nominative case, not the accusative.

> Natürlich blieb Einstein nicht ein Angestellter des Patentamtamts, sondern der Universität.
>
> *Of course, Einstein didn't stay as an employee in the patent office, but in the university.*

Comment: Der letzte Satz ist falsch, denn er blieb ja nicht ein Angestellter der Universität, sondern wurde es erst - soweit ich oberflächlich informiert bin.

Comment: Ich habe es in größerem zeitlichen Rahmen betrachtet, aber du hast natürlich Recht, wenn man es genau auf den Zeitpunkt auslegt. Grammatikalisch ist der Satz allerdings korrekt.